# Loading Shapefile in flexviewer 2.2

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-flex-api, flex

I want to load Shapefile in Flexviewer 2.2

Any sample would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the same widget updated for flex 2.2, linked in Simon Jackson's solution on the resource center.
[Load Shape file flex viewer 2.2](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=bc6a88cf51364d9ea767347954363d7d)

Answer (score 2):

Not tested this, but this [widget](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16846) could do what you want:

> DESCRIPTION:  To Allow the user to
>   select any shape file in zip format
>   (that is example.shp – for geometry
>   and example.dbf  - for Attributes, are
>   only files to be zipped) and display
>   over the current Map as graphics.
>   Actually it creates a custom geometry
>   to take advantage of the coordinate
>   array format in the shapefile reducing
>   the impedance and taking advantage of
>   the compression.  This an array of
>   x,y,x,y,etc... That’s all; it can then
>   be rendered with any symbol.
>
> ASSUMPTIONS: Only Polygon shape file
>   to be added is allowed as current
>   limitation but for sure libraries are
>   ready that are open to be extended and
>   customized as you want.

I also remember reading Mansour's blog (Heads up Esri Flex team) and he has [a post](http://thunderheadxpler.blogspot.com/2009/09/map-layer-from-local-shapefile.html) on how to achieve this in a native Flex app.